# Petición ajax POST a un @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, post, axios

Tengo una aplicación Java Web con Spring, en la cual tengo un @Controller con mi método de la siguiente manera:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/autos")
public class AutoController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AutoService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody AutoBean insertar(AutoBean bean) {
        return service.guardar(bean);
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Pretendo hacer una solicitud vía Ajax utilizando axios de la siguiente manera:

```
if (isValid) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let obj = {
        "descripcion": $('#descripcion').val(),
        "marca": $('#marca').val(),
        "stock": $('#stock').val(),
        "precio": $('#precio').val()
    };

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
    axios.post('autos', obj, headers)
    .then(function(response) {
        swal("Correcto!", "Se ha registrado!", "success");
        ...
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
        swal("Ha ocurrido un error!", "Error en el sistema", "error");
    });
    
    ...
}
```

La petición llega al servidor pero el parámetro tiene los campos vacíos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentando retirando el header de la petición Ajax per el problema persiste. Para peticiones Get si lo he conseguido pero me he liado con el Post.

Comment: Intenta agregando la anotacion @RequestBody al parametro del metodo asi: `public @ResponseBody AutoBean insertar(@RequestBody AutoBean bean)`

Answer (score 0):

en el parametro del método usa @RequestBody así:

```
    public @ResponseBody AutoBean insertar(@RequestBody AutoBean bean)
```

de esta manera el método será capaz de leer la información que le envías.